# get displayed value from listbox or drop-down box by Infopath/sharepoint2010

Tags: infopath

When get a value from list of drop-down box tied to data-source of sharepoint list and send it to text-box by rule it shows the value of the index.

### How can I send displayed value or convert the value of index into displayed value?

add more info;
Thank you for answering. but if change ID to Title, an error of "only positive integers allowed". refer to [custom list form - only positive integer allowed in dropdown](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/9870/custom-list-form-only-positive-integer-allowed-in-dropdown). What I originally try to do is prepare 2 drop-boxes(db1, db2) associated with each different field in the a same data-source of a sharepoint list and filter a list of the candidates in db2 by the selected value in db1. Any best practice?
Hiro
[image]

Answer (score 0):

In the source drop down list properties, you can specify what the display value and what the index value is. Typically it defaults to the Title as to the display value and the ID as the ID. Simply change it to Title. and it will pass the title to the other text box.

Comment: Thank you for answering. but if change ID to Title, an error of "only positive integers allowed". refer to http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/9870/custom-list-form-only-positive-integer-allowed-in-dropdown.